# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then') when using useNavigate

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to redirect a user to `"/myblogs"` page when they submit a post after editing. `useNavigate` hook was used to redirect. Instead of redirecting, I get the following error.
When I manually check my blog page, I can see the updated post. I have no idea why this error occurs

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(inputs);
  sendRequest().then(data =>
    console.log(data).then(() => navigate('/myBlogs/'))
  );
};
```

error in my console

```
BlogDetail.jsx:51 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
```

Here is my full code

```
const BlogDetail = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [blog, setBlog] = useState();
  const id = useParams().id;
  console.log(id);
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({});

  const { title, descritpion, imageURL } = inputs;

  const handleChange = e => {
    setInputs(inputs => ({
      ...inputs,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  const fetchDetails = async () => {
    const res = await axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/blog/${id}`)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
    const data = res.data;
    return data;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDetails().then(data => {
      setBlog(data.blog);
      setInputs({
        title: data.blog.title,
        descritpion: data.blog.description,
        imageURL: data.blog.image,
      });
    });
  }, [id]);

  const sendRequest = async () => {
    const res = await axios
      .put(`http://localhost:5000/api/blog/update/${id}`, {
        title: inputs.title,
        descritpion: inputs.description,
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
    const data = await res.data;
    return data;
  };

  console.log(blog);
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(inputs);
    sendRequest().then(data =>
      console.log(data).then(() => navigate('/myBlogs/'))
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` is a void return (*i.e. returns `undefined`*), it doesn't return any Promise object to chain from. Just issue the imperative navigation after the log statement.

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(inputs);
  sendRequest()
    .then(data =>
      console.log(data);
      navigate('/myBlogs/');
    );
};
```

Comment: i changed the following code to this and it works for me `sendRequest().then((data) => console.log(data)).then(() => navigate('/myBlogs/'))` thanks

Answer (score 0):

i changed my code to

```
sendRequest().then((data) => console.log(data)).then(() => navigate('/myBlogs/'))
```

from this

```
sendRequest().then(data =>
  console.log(data).then(() => navigate('/myBlogs/'))
);
```

and it works